# select data of one column on basis on another column in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create an excel sheet in which I have one column which stores the date of a software release and just right to it is stored whether that release rejected in the form of yes or no. something like this:

```
Release Date    Rejected   
25/01/2015        No  
26/02/2015        No  
30/03/2015        No  
01/05/2015       Yes
```

With this I am maintaining another table in same sheet which gives total number of releases and rejected releases till a particular month something like this:

```
Year = 2015      No. of release       No of rejected release    
Month        Till month   IN month    Till month    IN month
January           1         1       
February          2         1       
March             3         1       
April             3         0       
May               4         1
```

If you see in result table, no of release till MAY are 4 and in the month of may it is only one. This I am doing by comparing all dates in "release date" column with 31/05/2015 and counting all dates before that.
Similarly I want to do for number of rejected release. for example for month of May, count all release dates before 31/05/2015 and then from that count only those release which are rejected on basis of yes or no.
Can anyone please help as I am not able to figure out the formula for this.

Comment: sorry for the table content mis allignment

Comment: [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) should be what you need...